# How to prove that the set of all exchangeable events is a sigma-algebra?

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $ \{X_n\}_n $ be sequence of identical R.Vs.
Mark by $S$ the set of all sequences available from it.
An exchangeable event is $E\subset S $ which is not sensitive for finite permutations.

$P(X_1=x_1,\ldots)=P(\sigma(x_1),\ldots) $ when $\sigma$ is a finite permutation.

The book says it is easy to prove that set of all exchangeable events is a $\sigma$-algebra.

I have already showed that any countable intersection of finite permutations is a finite permutation.

I have already claimed that $\emptyset$ is an exchangeable event.

Now all I need to show is that the complementary event is an exchangeable event.
And I have no idea how.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can anyone help?

Comment: Showing that a countable intersection of finite permutations is a finite permutation is not the same as showing that a acountable intersection of events invariant under finite permutations is an event invariant under finite permutations. $\qquad$

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Write $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle\sim\langle y_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ if and only if there is a finite permutation $\sigma$ such that $y_n=\sigma(x_n)$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$. Check that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $S$. Show that an event is exchangeable if and only if it is a union of $\sim$-equivalence classes. Since the $\sim$-equivalence classes partition $S$, it follows immediately that the complement of an exchangeable event is exchangeable.

Comment: M.Scott, Well, it actually helped me to define a group on the set of partitions, hence proving what I needed. Thank you.

Comment: @JonesY: You’re welcome.